# Trying to create a KDE Plasmoid which retrieves a specific Category of apps

Tags: kde, plasma

I apologize in advance if this question will sound a bit too generic.

I am new to this; all I have done so far is modifying a few existing plasmoids to my needs.

Now I am trying to put together a plasmoid that will retrieve the “content” of one and only one category of apps: “internet”, “games”, etc.

I have been trying to figure out this by studying the "kickoff" Application Launchers available on Plasma, but they all seem very intricate.

The Plasmoid development or API docs also doesn't seem to explain this in any digestible way.

If I understand it correctly, the system provides (how?) a mixed list of apps and categories, among which it's possible to discriminate, using the `isCategory` property?

Even if this is true, how is the loading of this mixed list of apps and categories achieved? is this done via `PlasmaCore`? Is it done using the `kicker 0.1` component? How?